# windows update error 0x80070522 trying to update the OS using downloaded .exe, more info below:

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I am trying to install windows update on my PC. It is a windows 10 64-bit Lenovo yoga. I download an exe off of this site https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

I for some reason download and install it almost the entire way when the error comes up. I looked up the error and it has something to do with the windows update client not having access to my system. The code translates to “A required privilege is not held by the client.”

I bought Minecraft on Microsoft store but it has an OS version requirement so it has an update button which is what I press to get onto the site. Heres a screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oinl.png)

Comment: Did you disable encryption/bitlocker/etc?

Comment: what is this encryption BitLocker?

Comment: Its a way to protect your data. Never mind this if you have not used it. More importantly: Are you using an administrative account to make the update ?

Comment: yes i am using an administrative account

Comment: why are you not using Windows update?

Comment: I bought Minecraft on the Microsoft store and it has a system requirement for me to update my computer. I will add screenshot to my question. I click on the update butter to update my OS and it sends me to this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 so i just install it from there.

Comment: Use windows update : select the Start  button > Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Update , and then select Check for updates.

Comment: I have done that. It just says my device may be at risk because I don't have a newer OS version.

Comment: See the Advanced section on this page to reset windows updates>>>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4089834/windows-10-troubleshoot-problems-updating?ocid=20SMC10164Windows10

Comment: @Titaniumammas69 Try running Windows update troubleshooter : https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter

Comment: What is your windows 10 OS build number ?

Comment: I have tried running the troubleshooter several times and my windows 10 OS build number is 15063.786 however the requirement is 17134.0 or higher.

Comment: also when i try connect to the update checker thingy there is always an error saying they couldnt connect to the update service however i have internet, and wifi. I even tried using a VPN but it still didnt work